# Obtain reflectance map in pix4d?

Tags: coordinate-system, reflectance, pix4d

I can not obtain my reflectance map in pix4D.

The program said:

> Unable to computed radiometric calibraticon from sequoia. Unable to
>   computed coordinated system.

Its rare, because normally i can obtain my maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calibration images may be under or over exposed. Sequoia takes three sets of images every time, you may try switching the calibration images. Moreover rather than using the default calibration area,you may try to create your own calibration area that is not under or over exposed.